# How can i remove item from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

1. need to convert input value to array type `[[X,Y,Z],[A,B,C]]`
2. I want to remove item from array just on click.

```js
$(".btn-primary").click(function () {
  var nbrOfList = 2; // number of item went to remove
  var _data1 = $('#listAllEmp').val(); // default value
  var _data2 = eval("[" + _data1 + "]"); // convert as array

  var itemtoRemove = _data2[nbrOfList-1]; // itemtoRemove from array
  _data2.splice($.inArray(itemtoRemove ,_data2),1); // Remove from array


  jQuery('#listAllEmp').val('[' + _data2 + ']'); // new value after remove
  $('p').text('[' + _data2 + ']')
  
});
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="" id="listAllEmp" value='["job name 1","nat 1"],["job name 2","nat 2"],["job name 3","nat 3"]' />

<a title="" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0);">remove 2 item</a>
<p></p>
```

Comment: you meant `array.splice`?

Comment: 1 - Learn how to use Markdown. 2 - See [ask] page as well.

Answer (score 0):

use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
   jQuery('#listAllEmp').val(JSON.stringify(_data2));
      $('p').text(JSON.stringify(_data2))
```

and [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) instead of eval ( Using eval is not a good practice )

```
JSON.parse('[["job name 1","nat 1"],["job name 2","nat 2"],["job name 3","nat 3"]]')
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and proper regexp solution for input value to array conversion. Then after deleting or inserting items a simple map implementation to get value back into string to be inserted in your DOM element.

So once you have this array you can delete or add items to it through your event listener and insert it back into the value property of the element. Ok let's assume we are to delete item at index 1. Please see the following code

```js
var _data1 = '["job name 1","nat 1"],["job name 2","nat 2"],["job name 3","nat 3"]',
       reg = /([^"]+)","([^"]+)/g,
    _data2 = [];

while(_data2[_data2.length]=reg.exec(_data1));
_data2 = _data2.slice(0,-1).map(c => c.slice(1,3)); // now we have our array in _data2

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(_data2) + "</pre>\n");

_data2.splice(1,1); // item at index 1 is removed from _data2
_data1 = _data2.map(e => "[" + e + "]").join(","); // _data1 is ready to be sent to value

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(_data1) + "</pre>\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your code a bit as below, hope it can fulfill your need.

```js
$(".btn-primary").click(function () {
  var nbrOfList = 2;
  var data1 = $('#listAllEmp').val(); // default value
  var _data2 = data1.split("],["); // convert as array
  
  $('#test').html("<b>Before Remove</b>:--<pre>"+_data2+"</pre>"); //Before remove
      
  //_data2.pop(2); //Removing last element 
  _data2.splice((_data2.length)-2,nbrOfList)
  
  $('#test').append("<b>After each click</b>:--<pre>"+_data2+"</pre>"); //After Remove
      
  var numbersString = _data2.join('],['); // Again making string to follow your format
      
  //Assigning new value to textbox
  if(numbersString == "")
    $('#listAllEmp').val("");
  else
    $('#listAllEmp').val(numbersString+"]"); 
  
  $('#test').append("<b>New String</b>:--   "+$('#listAllEmp').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="" id="listAllEmp" value='["job name 1","nat 1"],["job name 2","nat 2"],["job name 3","nat 3"]' />

<a title="" class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0);">remove 2 item</a>
<p></p>
 <div id="test" style="width:100%;height:50%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to remove item from an array You can do something like this:

```
var y = [1, 2, 2, 3, 2]
var removeItem = 2;

y = jQuery.grep(y, function(value) {
  return value != removeItem;
});
```

Result:

```
[1, 3]
```